# How to deactivate ALL transitions/fades/motions in iOS 9?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, accessibility

Is there a way to deactivate ALL transitions, fade and motions effects throughout the iOS?

When I tap on the Safari app, say, I want to open Safari immediately, not sit through a split-second of fade motions before opening Safari. When rapidly switching between apps this is very aggravating.

I'm already on Reduce Motion and Reduce Transparency. But I want to go beyond this and have no motion whatsoever.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible, unless you jailbreak.

Comment: If jailbreaking remains the only option: does anyone know more about this, which apps could accomplish this, etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Jailbreak Solution

**1. Speed Intensifier** - has tons of options to change

Add Philip Wong’s  repo at: https://pw5a29.github.io/ and add it as a Cydia source.

[image]

**2. NoSlowAnimations** - has only few options to change

[image]

NoSlowAnimations is available in the BigBoss repo on the Cydia store. BigBoss is already available in Cydia as one of the default repos.

Answer (score 0):

It actually happens on my iphone6S Plus recently, I just turned on "Reduce Motion", and it did disable all the transitions as well as fade, but when I try turned it off and turned back on, it no longer behave like that.